# Use box api oauth without making the user enter credentials

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

I am trying to use the Box SDK For Android but it always makes me enter my Box credentials (username and password).  How can I make it so that I don't have to enter a username and password each time.  Their documentation is really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

When you authenticate with Box you'll receive an OAuth2 access/refresh token pair that are used to make API calls. Box intends for you to save the access/refresh tokens on the device. The Android SDK should store them in [shared preferences by default](https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk/blob/master/doc/Authentication.md#security) and automatically refresh the token for you as needed. You might confirm that the tokens are being saved in the shared preferences as a first step in debugging this further.

Comment: Is it possible to use the refresh token when using JWT ?

Comment: The JWT flow doesn't use refresh tokens. When the access token expires, you simply request a new access token. I would expect that the SDK does this automatically.